# VBS - Loop through multiple .csv files in a folder and convert the files to .xlsx

Tags: csv, vbscript, xlsx

I managed to get the following piece of code put together:

```
'Constants
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51             '(without macro's in 2007-2016, xlsx)
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52 '(with or without macro's in 2007-2016, xlsm)
Const xlExcel12 = 50                     '(Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2016 with or without macro's, xlsb)
Const xlExcel8 =56                       '(97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2016, xls)

' Extensions for old and new files
strExcel = "xlsx"
strCSV = "csv"

' Set up filesystem object for usage
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Get folder name to process off the command line, make sure it's valid
If (WScript.Arguments.Count > 0) Then
    strFolder = WScript.Arguments(0)
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
        WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "Specified folder does not exist."
        WScript.Quit
    End If
Else
    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "No folder name specified to process."
    WScript.Quit
End If

' Access the folder to process
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

' Load Excel (hidden) for conversions
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

' Process all files
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    ' Get full path to file
    strPath = objFile.Path
    ' Only convert CSV files
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strPath)) = LCase(strCSV) Then
        ' Display to console each file being converted
        WScript.Echo "Converting """ & strPath & """"
        ' Load CSV into Excel and save as native Excel file
        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath, False, True)
        objWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(strPath, strCSV, strExcel), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        objWorkbook.Close False
        Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    End If
Next

'Wrap up
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Unfortunately I have 3 issues:

1. I was instructed to run this in the following manner:
   Copy the code above and saved it as `csv.vbs`
   Go to CMD and type in

   ```
   cscript csv.vbs "C:\Users\Eitel\Desktop\3rd Party\Work Folder"
   ```

   This is the path where the CSV files are.

   I would prefer to have a way of executing the code by clicking on/opening a VBScript.
2. I received this error:

   > Input Error: Can not find script file "C:\Users\Eitel\csv.vbs"

   I went to *"C:\Users\Eitel\csv.vbs"* and pasted the `csv.vbs` file in this location. I ran the command again and this is what was displayed:

   > "C:\Users\Eitel\Desktop\3rd Party\Work Folder\TestFile.CSV"
   >   C:\Users\Eitel\csv.vbs(44.9) Microsoft Excel: Cannot save as that name. Document was opened as read-only.

   I have no clue what this means or why it happens?
3. I noticed that while most of the files are .csv extensions, some of the files extensions are displayed as .CSV and some are .csv. I am wondering if this will affect the way in which the script is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I needed:

Link: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29088597/Change-Multiple-csv-files-into-xlsx-files.html?notificationFollowed=205599875

```
'Constants 
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51             '(without macro's in 2007-2016, xlsx)
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52 '(with or without macro's in 2007-2016, xlsm)
Const xlExcel12 = 50                     '(Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2016 with or without macro's, xlsb)
Const xlExcel8 =56                       '(97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2016, xls)

' Extensions for old and new files
strExcel = "xlsx"
strCSV = "csv"
strXLS = "xls"

' Set up filesystem object for usage
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strFolder = "B:\EE\EE29088597\Files"

' Access the folder to process
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

' Load Excel (hidden) for conversions
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

' Process all files
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    ' Get full path to file
    strPath = objFile.Path
    ' Only convert CSV files
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strPath)) = LCase(strCSV) Or LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strPath)) = LCase(strXLS) Then
        ' Display to console each file being converted
        Wscript.Echo "Converting """ & strPath & """"
        ' Load CSV into Excel and save as native Excel file
        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath, False, True)
        strNewPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(strPath) & "\" & objFSO.GetBaseName(strPath) & "." & strExcel
        objWorkbook.SaveAs strNewPath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        objWorkbook.Close False
        Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    End If
Next

'Wrap up
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

This will scan the directory for any xls or csv file and convert them into xlsx files.

Comment: For full reference of possible extensions here anyone can find the different values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat